# Can a Smart Contract call itself?

Tags: solidity, inheritance

Suppose I have contract A. Contract B inherits Contract A. Suppose updateB() is called in contract A from an EOA. Now inside update(), a function in contract B is called. Will msg.sender be that of the EOA or will it be address(this), the address of the smart contract ?

```
Import ./IContractB

Contract A {

     function updateB() external {
       IContractB(address(this)).update()
     }
}

Contract B is Contract A {

    function update() external {
      require(msg.sender == address(this);
      //logic
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

when `updateB()` is called on Contract A from an EOA, `msg.sender` within `updateB()` is the EOA. However, when Contract A then calls `update()` in Contract B using `IContractB(address(this)).update()`, the `msg.sender` within the `update()` function is set to the address of Contract A, because Contract A is the one executing the call to `update()`.